# A very small exponential number in php

Tags: php

I have a very small exponential number and it display like:

5.2255534523412e-7

Can I display it become:

5.22e-7

Comment: "5.2255534523412e-7" - this is stored as string?

Answer (score 1):

Use sprintf() to format the output

http://php.net/sprintf

```
$a = 5.2255534523412e-7;

// change 2 to be how many decimal places you want. The e treats it as scientific notation.
echo sprintf('%.2e', $a);
```